# How to make application wait until OnAppearing is finished?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation

In my Xamarin.Forms application on the iOS platform, I have found that the application freezes when switching through navigation pages for a while. I deduced that the application started changing pages before the original page was finished loading.

```
2018-08-14 13:44:26.355 MC_Phone.iOS[1943:245399] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_NavigationRenderer_ParentingViewController: 0x10be550d0>.
```

From this, I think that I need for the OnAppearing function of each page to make the application wait until the page is finished, but there are no asynchronous calls that I need to make on the OnAppearing function, only changing the values of the page. How would I make the application load the current page before switching to other pages using this OnAppearing function, or what other solution would be easier to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Try initialize them before invoking, kind of like..

Instead of:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SecondPage());
```

Something like this:

```
SecondPage secondPage = new SecondPage();
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(secondPage);
```

Edit: Could you provide some code? specially from what's happening on the appearing

Comment: Don't you think this will only call the constructor and not OnAppearing

Comment: Im assuming he has something too heavy slowing him either in the constructor or the OnAppearing, but.. with out code it's hard to know.. im guessing